# HttpClient.SendAsync() is not sending JSON as string

Tags: .net-core, httpclient, dotnet-httpclient

I'm having trouble figuring out what's wrong with HttpClient script.

When I use Fiddler, it works & AspNetCore MVC isn't throwing errors.

```
 http://localhost:6004/api/XUnitExamplesTest/JsonStringMethod

 Http-Get

 User-Agent: Fiddler
 Accept: text/json
 Content-Type: text/json
 Host: localhost:6004
 Content-Length: 24

 "{\"Color\": \"Green\"}"
```

But HttpClient script causing AspNetCore MVC issues.

```
var sampleData = new XUnitSampleData() { Color = "Red" };
var contentType = "text/json";
var httpMethod = HttpMethod.Get;
var uriPath = "JsonStringMethod";
var jsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(_sampleData, Formatting.None).ToString();  // JSON String.  --> "{ \"Vin\" : \"foo\", \"Color\" : \"foo\" }"
var jsonRequest = string.Format("\"{0}\"", jsonData);

var result = await XUnitWebClient.GetAsync3(contentType, httpMethod, uriPath, jsonRequest, CancellationToken.None);


public static async Task<string> GetAsync3(string contentType, HttpMethod httpMethod, string uriPath, string request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())  
    {
        using (var httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(httpMethod, string.Format("{0}{1}", _uri, uriPath)))
        {
            httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(string.Format("{0}", _baseAddress));

            //httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue(contentType));  // "Accept" Header.

            //httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Remove("Content-Type");
            //httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Content-Type", contentType);

            httpRequestMessage.Content = new StringContent(request, Encoding.UTF8, contentType);  // "Content-Type" Header.

            var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage);

            return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

AspNetCore MVC got the JSON value as `"{"`.

Since I'm using text/json so how do I tell HttpClient to send json string with beginning quote and ending quote, instead of it stripping that out?

Or am I doing something wrong with JsonConvert.SerializeObject() here?

Comment: Client side, or Server side?  The double quotes at both end of JSON string, when I ran it through https://www.freeformatter.com/json-validator.html , it said it is valid JSON string.  So, it should work on Client Side (HttpClient) when sending to ServerSide (AspNetCore MVC).  The AspNetCore MVC won't accept it without having double quote on both ends for text/json

Comment: In answer to your question, regarding Fiddler sample.  If without double double quote on both ends, result in AspNetCore MVC exception where Newtonsoft.Json.JsonInputFormatter & Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException ran into an error.  But it works just fine having double quotes on both end.

Comment: I stand corrected - a JSON _string_ is itself valid JSON, technically. Still, it is very awkward to require the client to stingify the JSON rather than just send it directly. I'll attempt to answer.

Comment: One other observation - it's not very common to send a JSON body (or any body) in a GET request. Is `color: green` a list filter or something similar? It's far more common to pass that as a query string parameter.

Comment: My hand are tied.  Had to comply with 3rd party provider which are stuck in it's own integration mess.  Lot of it's customers are using it though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**To answer the question directly...**

You're not escaping the quotes *inside* the JSON string. Try this:

```
var jsonRequest = string.Format("\"{0}\"", jsonData.Replace("\"", "\\\""));
```

**However...**

I question how you're approaching this problem. You mention in your comments that you get an error on the server side (in your MVC code) if you don't stringify the JSON on the client side. However, it is very awkward and non-standard to require the client to do this. I would:

1. Change the content type from `text/json` to `application/json`. That won't fix the problem, but it is the standard.
2. Remove the line above and send `jsonData` directly. i.e. don't stringify the JSON.
3. Ask a new question about how to solve the server-side error you're getting, and post the relevant MVC code.

Comment: How come double slashes in `Replace()` object?  What does it do?

Comment: It escapes the escape character. `"\\"` in C# will render literally as \, which is what you want to end up with here. You are effectively double escaping, which is why it looks odd.

Comment: Actually, I just updated it - you  need 3 backslashes there. The first escapes the second, and the third escapes the quote. Confusing enough? :)

Comment: Thanks for the edit.  The 3rd party provider require text/json.  :-/  So, I'm building the client to emit the 3rd party provider, as part of xUnit Test so we don't break anything when a future upgrade is made.  :-/